# Hosting ASP.NET application with SQL Server DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webfaction

I have a web site developed in ASP.NET MVC and used MS SQL Server as a back-end database. 
I was trying to host this application on webFaction, but unable do do so as it seems WebFaction does not support hosting of ASP.NET applications.

Can I host ASP.NET application with SQL Server as DB on WebFaction?

Comment: i think i would be better if you contact WebFaction. This is not the place.

Comment: Have you ever tried to post one on WebFaction,, They are struggling at the moment to save a question. Giving me a server error 500. Hence here. @Manish

Comment: @DDeshmane what i would say is before choosing WebFaction you would have inquired properly whether they allow asp.net application hosting or not. And now also what i would suggest is contact with them, they are guys who can address your query the best.

Comment: @Manish Exactly if I was to choose the hosting environment, i would have did the same. But its my client who has come up with this hosting environment. And now apart from advice if you really have some valuable sharing please post.(I can not contact WebFaction)

Comment: You can: https://www.webfaction.com/contact/. Also, searching the web for "webfaction windows hosting" or "asp.net site:https://www.webfaction.com" doesn't yield anything usable. So more advice: don't let your clients buy hosting, or at least not before you specified the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is here: https://community.webfaction.com/questions/17081/asp-as-application/17099

WebFaction only offers Linux server hosting.

If you want to use ASP.Net, you'll have to use Mono. They don't provide an installer for it, so you'll need to build the Mono stack from scratch.

Per MS SQL server, it doesn't (currently) run on Linux. So you will either need to connect your Webfaction ASP app to another hosting service for the database, switch to a new database, or wait for MS to release their linux version of MS SQL.